# How should buttons be placed

Tags: c#, android, xaml, user-interface

How should buttons be placed inside a relative layout ?

I'm building my first android app and I want my buttons appear nicely on all devices. I don't want to move around and appear pretty much anywhere so I want to see their position in a relative layout with a bottom gravity. Now, if I put two buttons in that layout, how can I place relatively inside that layout ?

If I put them like this :

```
 <RelativeLayout
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="117.0dp"
    p1:layout_gravity="bottom"
    p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
    <Button
        p1:text="Button"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="61.2dp"
        p1:id="@+id/button1" />
    <Button
        p1:text="Button"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="61.2dp"
        p1:id="@+id/button2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Both button will appear on top of each other. **But if I used Margins to separate them from each other, they won't have the same separation size on all devices**. How could I make it so that these two buttons would be next top each other (one on top one on the bottom) and make sure that it stays like this on all devices ?

This is what I have at the moment :

```
----------------------------
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|--------------------------|    <------ (Top linear layout / bottom relative layout)
|                          |
|     Button 1 AND 2       |
|                          |
|                          |
----------------------------
```

This is what I need but I cannot use margins

```
----------------------------
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|--------------------------|    <------ (Top linear layout / bottom relative layout)
|                          |
|     Button 1             |
|                          |
|     Button 2             |
----------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having this should help across all devices:

```
<RelativeLayout
  p1:minWidth="25px"
  p1:minHeight="25px"
  p1:layout_width="match_parent"
  p1:layout_height="117.0dp"
  p1:layout_gravity="bottom"
  p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
    <Button
        p1:text="Button"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="61.2dp"
        p1:id="@+id/button1" />
    <Button
        p1:text="Button"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="61.2dp"
        p1:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1/>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

These ensure relativity

```
android:layout_toRightOf
android:layout_toLeftOf
android:layout_below
```